# Changing the TransactionScope IsolationLevel to Snapshot in Inmemory DB

Tags: c#, sqlite, ormlite-servicestack, in-memory-database

I am using the in-memory database (using ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Windows) for unit testing in servicestack based web API. the method I am trying to test is as follows.

```
public object Get(object request)
{
    using (var db = HostContext.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().OpenDbConnection("ConnectionString"))
    {                           
        using (var dbtran = db.OpenTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot))
        {
            // reading operation from DB
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

when I tried to test this method using InmemoryDB connection getting the following Exception because of IsolationLevel.

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
> System.Data.SQLite.dll but was not handled in user code

I tried to set the isolation level to snapshot while creating inmemoryDB as follows,

```
var isolationlevel = IsolationLevel.Snapshot;
db.OpenTransaction().IsolationLevel.Add(isolationlevel);
```

even after executing this the transaction level is appearing as Serializable and gets the same Exception.

is there any other way to set the Transaction Isolationlevel to Snapshot in in-memory DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sqlite doesn't support creating a `IsolationLevel.Snapshot` transaction but [SQLite's Isolation and Concurrency](https://www.sqlite.org/isolation.html) docs indicates SQLite exhibits "snapshot isolation" when [Write Ahead Logging](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) (WAL) mode is enabled by running "PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL" which you can set in OrmLite with:

```
db.ExecuteSql("PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL");
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.